# multiple separate parent selects on stored inner query

Tags: postgresql

I have a fairly complex subquery which I'd like to group in two ways. I don't want to call the inner query twice, with something like

```
select 
  count(*)...
  field_a
from (
   select ...complex query
)
group by field_a

select 
  count(*)...
  field_b
from (
   select ...complex query
)
group by field_b
```

I'd rather call the inner query once:

```
select 
  count(*)...
  field_a
from stored results = (
   select ...complex query
)
group by field_a

select 
  count(*)...
  field_b
from stored results = (
   select ...complex query
)
group by field_b
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Select "complex query" into #t, then in the second block, select * from #t, at the end (when done with #t)... drop table #t

Answer (score 0):

My background is in SQL Server, but for this kind of thing I'd either use a table variable (doesn't look like postgresql supports those) or a temporary table.

[Have a look at this link for how to do that in postgresql.](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-temporary-table/#:%7E:text=A%20temporary%20table%2C%20as%20its%20named%20implied%2C%20is,CREATE%20TEMPORARY%20TABLE%20temp_table%20%28%20%20...%20%29%3B)

Once you've got the temp table created with the columns you need you can change your `complex query` to insert into that tmp table.

After the data is inserted you can query it out as many different times as you'd like. Bear in mind that your tmp table is not persistent (thus temporary) and will automatically be dropped once your script is done.